# Ubuntu Cron ec2-create-snapshot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, amazon-ec2, snapshot

I have a new ec2 Ubuntu instance running. I have properly set up the ec2-api tools. I want to create a daily backup using the `ec2-create-snapshot` command.
Just to test it, I have my script, which is named `dailyBackup`, and located in the `/etc/cron.daily` directory. I have the `chmod +x` permissions set.
Its recognized when I do:

```
run-parts --test /etc/cron.daily
```

When I run the following script as such:

```
. dailybackUp
```

Code within **dailyBackup**

```
#!/bin/bash
#This creates a backup of the root and xvdf volumes associated with this instance.
echo "Modifying the timezone to us-west-2..."
export EC2_URL=https://ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
echo "Creating daily backup for root volume"
ec2-create-snapshot vol-id --description "SkySpark Linux Daily Backup Root"
echo "Creating daily backup for storage  volume"
ec2-create-snapshot vol-id--description " SkySpark Linux Daily Backup Storage "
```

I've omitted the volume ids, but, they're correct in my file.

It works just fine. This is the behavior I want. It backs up the volumes and I am able to view them in the console. I want this to occur daily.
But, I have to manually call my script. It doesn't automatically get executed daily as I'd expect. Am I missing a step? Are my files configured incorrectly? Is the `ec2-create-snapshot` command unable to be executed in a job? Do I need to do something with cron?

Question also asked [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/edit!default.jspa?messageID=552960).

Comment: Is your cron script owned by root and not writable by group or other? Also when you run the script manually, do you run is as root?

Comment: It was owned by root. I ran the following: 
    `sudo chown ubuntu:root dailyBackup`
It now reads       
    `-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu root 461 Jun 30 14:08 dailyBackup`
I am running the script manually as ubuntu.

Comment: @DavidLevesque, it might also be worth noting that before the `chown` the permissions were as such: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. 
I set up the `postfix` email service, and at once I was able to see the problem. It had nothing to do with `root` owning the file

You need to export the passwords in order to use the `ec2 tools`. I put the following at the top of my script, and now it works perfectly.

```
 export AWS_ACCESS_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxx"
 export AWS_SECRET_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```